Folder sorting using a different default column field takes a long time
I have a folder with a large number of items.
When using the system default settings, the items are loaded instantaneously.
When I have changed the default sorting preferences to instead use the "Date" column field, it is loading the items way slower.
How can I make the items load instantaneously with a non-default column field? Is there a way to index this field?

NOTE: I can live without the Today/Last week/... groups.

There is no way. Unless you use the default set, windows will list all info by opening each item and getting the data, slowly populating the fields. Sorting does this also.

Ypou likely do not need Group by, which slows the display in Explorer. Turn Group by off and select the Date (or other) column to sort-order (Sort by).


Press WindowsE to open Explorer

Open the folder to which settings should apply.

On the View tab, click the Group by button.

Select (None)

Click on the column header to select the Sort by field, e.g., Date.

Click that column again if you want to change sort order from Ascending to Descending.

If you want this setting to apply to all folders of a the current folder type (e.g.., Music, Documents, etc.):

Select the Options button.
In the Folder Options dialog, on the View tab, select Apply to Folders.




does not fix the long loading times; according to the comment above, it seems that it is not possible
